# Sending Cursor to ASP.net Application

Tags: asp.net, oracle, plsql

So in my oracle database i have a cursor that gets all the present users of an event. Now i want to send this cursor to my asp.net aplication however I do not know how to return this cursor or how to process the data from this cursor in my asp.net aplication (putting all the id's in a list)
my plsql command is as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function Aanwezigen
RETURN CURsOR
IS
aanwezigenid number(6);

 cursor c1 is
SELECT  ID FROM persoon WHERE ID IN (select reservering."persoon_id" from reservering where      reservering.ID IN (select reservering_eticket."reservering_id" from reservering_eticket where reservering_eticket."aanwezig" = 1));


BEGIN 
FOR aanwezigrec in c1
LOOP
  aanwezigenid := aanwezigrec.ID;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(aanwezigrec.ID);
 END LOOP;

 RETURN aanwezigenid;

 END Aanwezigen;
/
```

Now here the only thing i return is a number (do not know if there are 5 numbers in my cursor if i return them all) but i want to return the entire cursor instead.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you try this one this will return the you the cursor and then you can model it after function returns the values:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function Aanwezigen
RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
aanwezigenid sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
open aanwezigenid 
for 
SELECT  ID FROM persoon WHERE ID IN 
   (select reservering."persoon_id" from reservering where 
    reservering.ID IN 
      (select reservering_eticket."reservering_id" from reservering_eticket 
      where reservering_eticket."aanwezig" = 1));
RETURN aanwezigenid;
 END ;/
```